# how to store data , and add button in firefox / chrome javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, c++, firefox-addon

im beginner to java script / XUL development and c++ if needed .
i have 2 basic questions and i need some directions .
background : i like to build simple plugin that schedule by date actions  to preform.
1. can i store data ( dates + ids )  so the plug in could read and write to it , what is the limitations ?
2. what is the best way to add button to gmail , or you tube , is Grease monkey is the only way ?

Thanks for helping .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform automatic date operations, you need your own `Date()`function & these links wil help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started/XUL_user_interfaces
https://wiki.mozilla.org/XUL:Specs:DateTimePickers

Regarding read & write to any files in XUL javaScript is pretty simple:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO
http://puna.net.nz/archives/Code/Mozilla%20XUL%20LOG%20-%20read%20local%20files%20and%20write%20local%20files.htm

The above links explained very clearly to read & write any type of files in any bit format in a directory or in a local machine, there is no limitation.

I have no idea baout Grease Monkey but in XUL use ca use DOM function to create buttons & elements dynamically.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/button

http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/chapter-6/

Comment: i meant button inside web page

Comment: @user63898: it's possible. You can create it dynamically. check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:document.createElement